# Autocomplete field invisible

Tags: ajax

It seems like my data inside the autocomplete field is invisble for non-admins.

[image: Proof]

I tried targetting the autocomplete with CSS but nothing seemed to work

```
#autocomplete li:hover, #autocomplete li:focus{ 
background-color:#428bca;
color:green;
}

#autocomplete li.selected { 
  background-color:#428bca;
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: change to the default Drupal theme and test.

Comment: @NoSssweat Now it works, the problem has to be within Bootstrap .. But what?

Comment: uncheck aggregate css in `admin/config/development/performance` then use a live css editor such as Webdeveloper for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) or  [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and start deleting CSS code until you see the change that you need. Then you will know what line of code is affecting it and in what css file.

Comment: @NoSssweat whenever i disable "Print styles" or "Embedde styles" It's working, but when I compare the css (inspect element on textbox I see no changes.

Comment: I found somehting in bootstrap.css, if i changd the background color to red from the class "dropdown-menu" I saw the items appear. They were invisible due they have color white. But i can't add color:white that don't work :) did not found color white somewhere

Comment: maybe it's using the Hex white, so look for `#fff` or possibly RGB white which is `255`